# regex hanging my program

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to write a c++ regex to essentially match a few symbols and identifiers as part of a tokenizer. Currently, I have this:

*EDITED*

```
  regex tokens("([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(\\S?)|(\\S)")

  vector<string> identifiers(std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(),
      IDENTIFIER),std::sregex_token_iterator());
```

https://regex101.com/r/mFTC1Y/2

<s>The problem is, it hangs my program (just takes forever and I never get to the matches). I don't understand how that can be? The regex tester I'm using says it takes a bout 7ms to match...</s>

Please help!

JUST EDITED:  so this regex matches what I want, but only via group captures. If it parses:

```
main()
```

It will return

```
main(    // full match
main     // group 1
(        // group 2
```

new match

```
)        // full match
)        // group 3
```

I just want the group matches without having to explicitly check the respective groups (i.e. I just don't return the full match to me). How can I update my code to do that?

**EDIT**
So, this is the full, working code. I'd prefer it be more elegant.

```
        regex TOKENS("([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(\\S?)|(\\S)")

        auto identifier = sregex_iterator(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), TOKENS);
        auto it = sregex_iterator();

        for_each(identifier, it, [&](smatch const& m){

            string group1(m[1].str());
            string group2(m[2].str());
            string group3(m[3].str());

            if(isKeyword(keywords, group1))     cout << "<keyword> "    << group1 << " </keyword>"      << endl;
            else if(group1 != "")               cout << "<identifier> " << group1 << " </identifier>"   << endl;
            if (isSymbol(symbols, group2))      cout << "<symbol> "     << group2 << " </symbol>"       << endl;
            if (isSymbol(symbols, group3))      cout << "<symbol> "     << group3 << " </symbol>"       << endl;
});
```

Something more elegant would probably come at the cost of a very complex regex, or else a very clever one, since essentially what I'm trying to do is tokenize code into one of three types: KEYWORD, ID and SYMBOL - all with one regex. Next I'll have to tackle INT/STRING const and comments. What I'm trying to avoid is tokenizing char by char, because then I'll have even more control-flow statements (which I don't want).

Comment: Need more code and example inputs/outputs. But perhaps it's something in C++'s implementation of backreferences.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the regex library your using? (Are you positive that the regex is valid as far as the library you're using is concerned?)

Comment: What compiler?  Some don't even support std::regex properly, e.g. GCC 4.x.

Comment: Can you post an example that has three things: (1) the example before adding any Regex, (2) the results after you applied your own Regex, (3) and the results that you want this example to be.

Comment: @Ibrahim well currently this example works for me, it's just that I have to implement some ugly control-flow logic to get the right output when I want it. Eg, in the case of matches, there will only be ( Group 1&2 match || Group 3 match). Knowing that and checking against the null ("") case, I can get the desired results (albeit, not elegant). See edit for current working code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if your regex is correct.

Try the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

// Our test data (raw string). So, containing also \n and so on
std::string testData(
R"#( :-)  IDcorrect1 _wrongID I2DCorrect
    3FALSE lowercasecorrect Underscore_not_allowed
i3DCorrect,i4 :-)
}
)#");

std::regex re("(\\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\b)");

int main(void)
{
    // Define the variable id as vector of string and use the range constructor to read the test data and tokenize it
    std::vector<std::string> id{ std::sregex_token_iterator(testData.begin(), testData.end(), re, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator() };

    // For debug output. Print complete vector to std::cout
    std::copy(id.begin(), id.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

All IDs will be in the vector. Then you can further check.

Comment: Don’t remember how I solved it, but I did eventually. It’s been a couple years.